# Eclipse isn't starting

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

So I downloaded Eclipse Kepler for a beginner's course in java programming. After completing a few activities, I took a break for about a month. **None of these programs are really important, so if I need to delete them, that's fine.** When I went to open eclipse for an activity about a week ago, I double clicked it and nothing happened. Occasionally, if I moved Eclipse to another folder or something, it would give me a warning message about how it couldn't locate its partner in a shared library. So then I googled my problem and found a solution about deleting something in the workspace/.metadeta/.plugins but I couldn't find that directory. I'm assuming that "workspace" is supposed to be a folder in the C:\eclipse, which is where I installed eclipse, but I couldn't find it anywhere. I found a folder just called "plugins", but deleting that didn't help at all. Finally, I uninstalled and reinstalled it to no avail, then I installed Eclipse Luna I think it's called (whatever is the most recent eclipse to download on the eclipse website) and it wouldn't open either, but when I double clicked it, it sent me this pop-up.

(I would put the picture here, but apparently I need "10 reputation")

Not sure what that means.

But it did seem to be some sort of log and it said "Java was started but returned exit code 13" and then had a whole lot of text after that.

**TL;DR:**
Can't open Eclipse Kepler or the newer Eclipse. I also can't find the workspace/.metadata/.plugins directory thingy that supposedly solves this problem

Any ideas on how to get Eclipse working again?

Comment: Java PATH is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Open the  `eclipse.ini` file and add, (make sure it is before `-vmargs`):

```
-VM
[path to x64 verstion of jdk]
```

For example:

```
    -VM
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

Depends on your Java version, make changes to `jre7`. Also the reason is because you installed x64 version Eclipse, so you need to download x64 version `JDK`.